# how to fix npm issue on wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, npm

when I call any of the below commands

```bash
npm
npm start
npm run start
```

I get this

```bash
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is mentioned in the following sources, where various
solutions were suggested:

- [After installing npm on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 I get the message "/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938486/after-installing-npm-on-wsl-ubuntu-20-04-i-get-the-message-usr-bin-env-bash)
- [/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory: Incompatible line-endings (WSL?) #1725](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1725)

This might be enough :

1. From WSL run `sudo apt install nodejs npm` to install node & npm
2. From PowerShell/CMD run `wsl --shutdown` to restart the WSL service
3. Next in WSL run `which npm` to confirm it's installed [output: */usr/bin/npm*]

If this doesn't solve the issue, other solutions are suggested
in the above sources.